# Spark 2.4.x: Duplicate keys in map

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given the following two arrays columns in Spark:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        Row(
            [Row(x=0, y='a'), Row(x=1, y='b'), Row(x=0, y='c')]
        )
    ],
    ["col"]
)
df.show()

+------------------------+
|col                     |
+------------------------+
|[[0, a], [1, b], [0, c]]|
+------------------------+
```

I want to create a map using `map_from_entries`:

```
df.withColumn(
    "mapped", f.map_from_entries("col")
).show(truncate=False)


+------------------------+------------------------+
|col                     |mapped                  |
+------------------------+------------------------+
|[[0, a], [1, b], [0, c]]|[0 -> a, 1 -> b, 0 -> c]|
+------------------------+------------------------+
```

In Spark 2.4.x, the behavior of the map functions, is to duplicate the keys. In the example, we have two values (a, c) for the same key 0.

I am aware that Spark 3.x behaves differently using the configuration: `spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy=LAST_WIN`, the results of the same operation will be:

```
+------------------------+----------------+
|col                     |mapped          |
+------------------------+----------------+
|[{0, a}, {1, b}, {0, c}]|{0 -> c, 1 -> b}|
+------------------------+----------------+
```

where only the second value `c` for the key `0` is kept in the map.

I am wondering  if there is a way to obtain the same results using Spark 2.4.

Comment: I think you need to do an UDF for that.

Comment: This is an option, but I'd rather to avoid using udf with pyspark, because of the increased overhead exchanging data between JVM and python.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can try is to convert to RDD then back to dataframe.

```
df = df.withColumn("mapped", F.map_from_entries("col")).rdd.toDF()
df.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------+----------------+
|col                     |mapped          |
+------------------------+----------------+
|[[0, a], [1, b], [0, c]]|[0 -> c, 1 -> b]|
+------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Does the function `rdd` convert the data into a python object? 
If yes, it will be even more expensive than calling the udf, which convert only a column to a python object.

Comment: No it doesn't. It's just the API to operate with the RDD object underlying the DataFrame.

Comment: Actually, calling `rdd.toDF()` in PySpark triggers the conversion of the data in the JVM into Python objects. This looks more expensive than using the UDF, which only converts the map column in python dictionaries.

Comment: it that true? could you give me some references? thanks

Comment: I don't have a reference, but from a benchmark:
(1) using UDF to convert the map into dictionary: 1 min 36 sec
(2) using `df.rdd.toDF(schema=df.schema)`: 1 min 44 sec.

Not a big difference, but enough for thinking that everything is converted in Python from JVM, which it will explain the reason why the duplicated keys are dropped.
BTW: if you don't specify the schema in the `toDF` the computational time will increase.

Comment: I see, you are right. read some threads here on SO and it is exactly what you said. thanks

Comment: Yes, the reason why it worked is the same as the UDF. It converts the map values to python dictionaries, which can't have duplicated keys.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solutions as suggested by Steven is to use an udf:

```
s = t.MapType(t.IntegerType(), t.StringType())
@f.udf(s)
def fix_map(s):
    return s

df.withColumn(
    "mapped", fix_map(f.map_from_entries("col"))
).show(truncate=False)


+------------------------+----------------+
|col                     |mapped          |
+------------------------+----------------+
|[[0, a], [1, b], [0, c]]|[0 -> c, 1 -> b]|
+------------------------+----------------+
```

The map passed to the UDF in Python is converted to a a Python dictionary, which doesn't allow to have duplicated keys.
The drawback is the overhead required to exchange data between the JVM and the Python interpreter.